# Remove duplicate objects from child List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

I have a class Items and want to remove duplicates

```
public class Items
        {
            public List<int> Parts { get; set; }
            public int Total { get; set; }
        }
```

And here the sample data:

```
List<Items> items = new List<Items>()
            {
                new Items(){ Parts = new List<int> { 6, 4, 0, 2, 0 }, Total = 100},
                new Items(){ Parts = new List<int> { 6, 4, 0, 2, 0 }, Total = 100},
                new Items(){ Parts = new List<int> { 1, 5, 0, 7, 3, 2 }, Total = 80},
                new Items(){ Parts = new List<int> { 1, 5, 0, 7, 3, 2 }, Total = 80},
                new Items(){ Parts = new List<int> { 1, 0, 4, 1 }, Total = 64},
                new Items(){ Parts = new List<int> { 3, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1 }, Total = 125},
                new Items(){ Parts = new List<int> { 3, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1 }, Total = 125},
                new Items(){ Parts = new List<int> { 2, 0, 1 }, Total = 26}
            };
        }
```

How to remove the duplicates in the list by using Linq?

Comment: Why did you edit out `Title`?  Don't change questions after someone has made an answer based on your original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Distinct()` method from `System.Linq` namespace. But, first of all it must now how to compare your custom object instances. For this, you can implement `IEquatable<T>` interface:

```
public class Items : IEquatable<Items>
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public List<int> Parts { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Items other)
    {
        if (Total == other.Total && Parts.SequenceEqual(other.Parts))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Total.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
items = items.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: @fubo )) Yes, he changed his question after I made an answer.

Comment: @murtzi No problem, it was not hard for me to chaneg one property.